# Presto Hive SQL Error: mismatched input 'PARTITIONED'. Expecting: 'COMMENT', 'WITH', <EOF>

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, partitioning, presto

I am trying to create a Hive table with partitions but getting the above error. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.table_name
    (
    ID   varchar(20),
    name varchar(50)
    )
PARTITIONED BY (part_dt varchar(8), system varchar(5));
```

The code works without the partitioning clause. Something gives up during partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Statement is working in hive. Pls find below screenshot.
[image: sc]
Its possible that some of column names are reserved keywords and that is throwing error. if yes, you can use below SQL too.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.table_name
    (
    `ID`   varchar(20),
    `name` varchar(50)
    )
PARTITIONED BY (`part_dt` varchar(8), `system` varchar(5));
```

Comment: For some reason, doesn't work still. Tried that too.  Using ` I get "backquoted identifiers are not supported; use double quotes to quote identifiers" and using double quotes doesn't do anything different either.